# turtlebot (EU Flavor)

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a turtlebot from scratch using the Roomba 510.  I think I have made the correct cable connection but I am not sure about the baud rate.   Changing the baud rate from 57600 to 115200 the driver.py doesn't seem to change anything.  I am getting OI  charging error messages during bring-up minimal launch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12976/turtlebot-(eu-flavor)/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2012-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this by giving up on the circuit I saw on Flicker, and substituting a Freeduino USB bib to do the conversion between USB and the TTL level signals used by the ROOMBA. only three wires are needed - TXD, RXD, and GND.   I did not use the Signal labled DD from the Roomba - I think this is used for changing the baud rate and needs a special signal to do that.

This leads to a thought,  perhaps the entire Freeduino could be used and aqditional sensors like a Gyro chip can be wired in.  I am not sure how Turtlebot EU folks add the gyro.

On My Youtube cahnnel I have clips of my turtlebot in operation.

[YouTube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/Dr1Bot?feature=mhee)

I also have a servo magazine article in press

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0